# Display UIImageView contained in UITableViewCell fullscreen with animation when tapped

Tags: animation, uitableview, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've an `UIImageView` inside an custom `UITableViewCell` and want it to display fullscreen when I tap on it. I've attached a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UIImageView` and the image already resizes. The problem I have right now is that the image only moves inside the cell it is contained in, but it should in fact move out of it. I'd also like to put a black background behind the image.

Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I would say the culprit is most likely either the cell, or the cells content view is `clipsToBounds` enabled. Setting `[cell setClipsToBounds:NO];` should solve this problem.

However, if you're willing to take a new approach to this, it may be beneficial to instead of growing the cells imageView, add a new image above the tableview in the same location as the cell's image view and then grow that. This way you wouldn't have any undesirable behavior like being able to scroll the image view away because the table is still scrollable.